# accessing row record by id error in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created three models:

- `recruitment` has-many `attendance`
- `project_site` has_many `attendance`

In the attendance view form#action I'm storing `recruitment_id`, `date`, and `status`, and showing marked status on change.

But the error is once I mark attendance on one recruitment_id same status gets showed to all recruitment_id but in the backend it's stored only marked attendance with all attributes.

I want to show only marked status of all attendance of `recruitment_id` with their corresponding status.

form.html.erb

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="attendance-emp-name">Emp. Name</th>

          <% (1..(Time.days_in_month @project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%m").to_i)).each do |date| %>
                <th class="text-center"><%= date %></th>
          <% end %>

        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <% @recruitment.where(location: @project_site.site_id).each do |recruitment| %>
          <tr>
              <td class="attendance-emp-name"><%= recruitment.name %></td>

              <% (1..(Time.days_in_month @project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%m").to_i)).each do |date| %>
                    <td>


                      <%= form_with(model: attendance, :html => {:id => 'attendance-form-validation'}, url:[@project_site, @attendance], local: true) do |f| %>

                        <% if attendance.errors.any? %>
                          <div id="error_explanation">
                            <h2><%= pluralize(attendance.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this attendance from being saved:</h2>

                            <ul>
                            <% attendance.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                              <li><%= message %></li>
                            <% end %>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        <% end %>


                        <div>

                          <% if Attendance.where(attendance_date: (@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%Y-%m")+"-"+date.to_s)).first == nil %>
                          <div class="wrapper-class">
                            <%= f.select :status, [['P', 1], ['A', 2], ['H', 3], ['L', 4], ['WE', 5], ['CO', 6]], {}, { onchange: 'this.form.submit()', class: 'attendance-select-input' } %>
                          </div>
                          <% else%>
                            <% attendance_value =  Attendance.where(attendance_date: (@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%Y-%m")+"-"+date.to_s)).first.status %>
                              <%if attendance_value == 1 %>
                                <%="P" %>
                              <% elsif attendance_value == 2 %>
                                <%="A"%>
                              <%elsif attendance_value == 3 %>
                                <%="H"%>
                              <%elsif attendance_value == 4 %>
                                <%= "L" %>
                              <%elsif attendance_value == 5 %>
                                <%= "WE" %>
                              <%elsif attendance_value == 6 %>
                                <%= "CO" %>
                              <% end %>
                          <% end %>

                            <%= f.hidden_field :attendance_date, value: (@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%Y-%m")+"-"+date.to_s)%>
                            <%=f.hidden_field :recruitment_id, value: recruitment.id%>
                            <%=f.hidden_field :project_site_id, value: @project_site.id%>
                            </div>

                            <div>
                              <%# f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button primary small float-right' %>
                            </div>

                      <% end %>
                    </td>
              <% end %>

          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

once i mark attendance of one employee it stores correct in database with recruitment_id but in view it show same status in all column.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time your view calls `Attendance.where(attendance_date: ...)`, it executes a SQL query to pull a list of all Attendance records with the specified date. You then are just grabbing the first one out of the list, which will be the same one every time. (You're also executing the query twice -- once to check empty and again if it isn't empty, which is wasteful).

You say that Recruitment model `has_one` Attendance, so you should be get the person's associated Attendance by just calling `recruitment.attendance`, but just looking at the view I suspect it is really a `has_many` relationship (or should be). In a has_many situation, you could at least use `recruitment.attendances.find_by(attendance_date: ...)` to ensure you are getting the right attendance for the right person.

Comment: hey each recruitment will have each month attendance currently i am using has_many relation b/w recruitment and attendance. someone edited this to ```has_one```

Comment: ```recruitment.find_by(attendance_date: ...)``` generates error because ```attendance_date``` attribute is in Attendance table.

Comment: Apologies, that was a brain failure on my part. I meant ``recruitment.attendances.find_by``. I updated the answer. I should note again that that's the case if the association is ``has_many``. If it is ``has_one`` then just calling ``recruitment.attendance`` will give you the associated attendance.